# How to save created excel file to Client pc in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a excel report and html report in asp.net when I clik the button and my application create it and save to the client desktop but, it is not working correctly because excel file is creating in server's desktop. How can I fix this matter ?

Thank you for your reply.

```
string CurrentDate;
DateTime saveNow = DateTime.Now;
CurrentDate = saveNow.Date.ToShortDateString();
string reportContent = prepareHTM();

string pathFile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory) + "\\As_Build_Report_ "+ CurrentDate + ".html";

using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(pathFile, true))
{
    outfile.WriteLine(reportContent);
}
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathFile);
```

---

```
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
//Start Excel Application.
Excel.Application oXL = new Excel.Application();
oXL.Visible = true; //display Application .            
Excel._Workbook oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(missing));//create a new workbook.
Excel._Worksheet oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet; //create a sheet                

string CurrentDate;
DateTime saveNow = DateTime.Now;
CurrentDate = saveNow.Date.ToString();
int keep = 5;
string project = list[0].Project;
oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "MiKES Configuration Management __" + project + "__ As-Built Report";
oSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "Report Date :";
oSheet.Cells[3, 2] = CurrentDate;

oSheet.Cells[keep, 1] = "PART NO";
oSheet.Cells[keep, 2] = "REF.DES.";
oSheet.Cells[keep, 3] = "DESCRIPTION";
oSheet.Cells[keep, 4] = "SERIAL NO";
oSheet.Cells[keep, 5] = "C/S";
oSheet.Cells[keep, 6] = "D/C";
oSheet.Cells[keep, 7] = "REMARK";
keep++;
foreach(Classes.CMNewPart item in list)
{
    try
    {
        oSheet.Cells[keep, 1] = item.PartNo;
        oSheet.Cells[keep, 2] = item.RefDes;
        oSheet.Cells[keep, 3] = item.Description1;
        oSheet.Cells[keep, 4] = item.SerialNo;
        oSheet.Cells[keep, 5] = item.Cs;
        oSheet.Cells[keep, 6] = item.Dc;
        oSheet.Cells[keep, 7] = item.Remark;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
    keep++;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, if you are running this from a server, you should really consider using the OpenXML SDK (or some other solution) to generate your files instead of interop. And why would you make Excel visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send the file to client using Response object. To ignore the warning message like when client is opening the excel file -

[image]

To prevent this you need to mention the content type and length in the response 
use the sample code

```
//Read the Excel file in a byte array. here pck is the Excelworkbook              
Byte[] fileBytes = pck.GetAsByteArray();

//Clear the response               
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Cookies.Clear();
//Add the header & other information      
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
Response.CacheControl = "private";
Response.Charset = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "cache");
Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "60");
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",
"attachment; " +
"filename=\"ExcelReport.xlsx\"; " +
"size=" + fileBytes.Length.ToString() + "; " +
"creation-date=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("R") + "; " +
"modification-date=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("R") + "; " +
"read-date=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("R"));
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
//Write it back to the client    
Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
Response.End();
```

Comment: Not working for me. It returns my excel file in image data/base64 format and gives me err_response_headers_multiple_content_disposition in Chrome. Called this method from iFrame. $("#iframe").attr("src", "/Pages/JourneyPlan.aspx?download=true&fileName=" + data.d);

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting. This solution worked years ago. Browser and Excel both are updated and it might not work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can write excel file to response [HttpResponse.WriteFile Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile.aspx)

```
string CurrentDate;
DateTime saveNow = DateTime.Now;
CurrentDate = saveNow.Date.ToShortDateString();
string reportContent = prepareHTM();

string pathFile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory) + "\\As_Build_Report_ "+ CurrentDate + ".html";

using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(pathFile, true))
{
    outfile.WriteLine(reportContent);
}

System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(pathFile); 
Response.Clear(); 
Response.Charset="UTF-8"; 
Response.ContentEncoding=System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; 
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name); 
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());    
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";  
Response.WriteFile(file.FullName); 
Response.End();
```

Comment: This sever side code works for me. I uses iframe in Client side to call. 
<iframe id="iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>   $("#iframe").attr("src", "/Pages/JourneyPlan.aspx?download=true&fileName=" + data.d);

Answer (score 1):

One important thing to note so that the selected best answer works for you:
 You have to use to use a different library than the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel implied in the question. You have to use EPPlus. This is how you set it up in your project:

1. From Visual Studio's Package Manager Console, type: Install-Package EPPlus (this will install the library and the reference as needed)
2. Add this using statement (`using OfficeOpenXml;`)

And this is some sample code to create the excel package (pck) as referred to in the best answer:

```
    ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("exported data");
    // Excel sheet headings
    ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Column 1 title";
    ws.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Column 2 title";
```

Now you can use the code provided in the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly save it to a specific clientside location. What you can do is returning the file with that request so that on the browser side a "save file" dialog pops up.

Comment: how can I do this can you give me more information or simple code . Thanks

Comment: I'm on mobile. Will do that later today.